# C# OpenTK mouve object along with mouse movement

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I'm working with OpenGL (OpenTK library) for a while and now I'd like to select an object using mouse (which I will handle myself I think) and allow its movement along with mouse movement.

I'm looking for an algorithm that could help me translate 2D mouse coordinates to my XZ coordinates in 3D (my Y coordinate is constant and corresponds to my "ground" level unless there's another object at this place, it should place moved object at the top of it - but that I'll also handle myself using collision detection).

What I'm asking here is an algorithm to allow my object follow mouse cursor in relation to camera and projection matrix.

**UPDATE**

**I'm working with OpenGL 3.3+**

Comment: Well, I know that I should unproject, but.. I don't know how to find X and Z "where" Y = 0 for a ray vector.

Comment: once you got yout mouse unprojected (3d Point (on the screen Plane)) you can compute point with y=0 on the ray (Mouse3d->ViewVector) View vector= (EyeTarget - EyePos)